# Groovy: using ampersand in command line parameter

Tags: windows, command-line, groovy, ampersand, windows-console

Here is the groovy script:

```
param = args[0]
println(param)
```

Here is how I run it (Windows 7):

```
groovy test.groovy a&b
```

I expect this script prints a&b, but instead get *'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

I tried to put the argument (a&b in my case) in quotes but it doesn't help. With double quotes, the script hangs. With single quotes I get the same error like without any quotes.

**Question:** is it possible to take a string with ampersand as command line argument for groovy script?

Comment: Is that message coming from groovy itself or from windows shell? On MacOS it works perfectly fine with the following invocation: `groovy script.groovy a\&b`

Comment: Opal, it comes from windows shell. With a\&b, I have the same error: 'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: reproduced it. this is a windows command-line thing. there are a bunch of suggested fixes involving escaping with carat and using double-quotes, none of them seem to work.

Comment: Nathan, agree, I tried carat, backslash and quotes. Nothing worked. Am I the only person in the world who needs it?

Comment: just have tried `groovy test a^&b` and it did not work?  what "shell" are you using in windows?  just plain `cmd` or something else? i really doubt, that this is a groovy problem

Comment: cfrick, sure, I have tried a^&b and it didn't work. I am using plain cmd and it doesn't work. I think it's kind of a mixed problem, since ^ does work in plain batch scripts but doesn't work when & is used in cmdline parameter for groovy script.

Comment: to address a comment to someone, so that they get notified, put an @ before their name.

Comment: but the error message is the one from windows.  how would groovy ever print something like this?  does the quoting work if you do e.g. `dir a^&b`?

Comment: @cfrick, sure, the error message is from windows, but it doesn't help to solve the problem. When I do dri a^&b, I don't get this error ('b' is not recognized bla-bla-bla), just the "File not found" which is expected.

Comment: i'd drop the java tag, add windows-oid tags and see if this attracts attention in the windows crouds here on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When executing `groovy` on Windows, we actually execute `%GROOVY_HOME\groovy.bat` and then (from `groovy.bat`):

`"%DIRNAME%\startGroovy.bat" "%DIRNAME%" groovy.ui.GroovyMain %*`

If we look inside `startGroovy.bat`, we can see a really ugly hack to deal with arguments (excerpt below):

```
rem horrible roll your own arg processing inspired by jruby equivalent

rem escape minus (-d), quotes (-q), star (-s).
set _ARGS=%*
if not defined _ARGS goto execute
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:-=-d%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:"=-q%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:?=-n%

rem Windowz will try to match * with files so we escape it here
rem but it is also a meta char for env var string substitution
rem so it can't be first char here, hack just for common cases.
rem If in doubt use a space or bracket before * if using -e.
set _ARGS=%_ARGS: *= -s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:)*=)-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:0*=0-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:1*=1-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:2*=2-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:3*=3-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:4*=4-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:5*=5-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:6*=6-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:7*=7-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:8*=8-s%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:9*=9-s%
```

Therefore, inside `startyGroovy.bat` `"a&b"` is "*escaped*" to `-qa&b-q`, resulting in two commands inside the script, yielding

```
'b-q' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

and causing an infinite loop while "*unescaping*".

You can see it with `set DEBUG=true` before running your groovy script.

Adding another hack to the bunch of hacks, you can *escape* also `&` in a similar way in `startGroovy.bat` as follows:

```
rem escape minus (-d), quotes (-q), star (-s).
rem jalopaba escape ampersand (-m)
set _ARGS=%*
if not defined _ARGS goto execute
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:-=-d%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:&=-m%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:"=-q%
set _ARGS=%_ARGS:?=-n%
```

and *unescape*...

```
rem now unescape -s, -q, -n, -d
rem jalopaba unescape -m
rem -d must be the last to be unescaped
set _ARG=%_ARG:-s=*%
set _ARG=%_ARG:-q="%
set _ARG=%_ARG:-n=?%
set _ARG=%_ARG:-m=&%
set _ARG=%_ARG:-d=-%
```

So that:

```
groovy test.groovy "a&b"
a&b
```

Not sure if a clearer/more elegant solution is even posible in Windows.

You can see a similar case with `groovy -e "println 2**3"` that yields `8` in UNIX console but hangs (infinite loop) in windows.

Comment: thank you very much for the valuable comment! I tried this option earlier, but in my environment (Windows 7 x64) groovy test.groovy "a&b" just hangs...

Comment: let me go into it more deeply. It looks like I was wrong in escaping &. I will try more.